# Here is one possible way to find random rows in a table? Is there a better method?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have these four tables:

```
Store (
    row bigint,
    id uniqueidentifier,
    name varchar
)

Products (
    row bigint,
    id uniqueidentifier,
    storeID uniqueidentifier,
    productname varchar
)

Customer (
    row bigint,
    id uniqueidentifier,
    storeID uniqueidentifier,
    fName,
    lName,
    email
)

orders (
    row bigint,
    id uniqueidentifier,
    store_ID uniqueidentifier,
    cust_id uniqueidentifier,
    prod_id uniqueidentifier,
    date datetime
)
```

We need to find 30 random rows in the orders table for a particular store.

Here is my first try at it:

```
  select TOP 30 * from orders o inner join store s on o.Retailer_ID=s.ID
    where s.Name='XXXX' and  o.Row in (select  ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS      
               VARBINARY) AS int)) %100000  from orders) and o.Retailer_ID =(select ID 
                  from store s where s.Name= 'XXXX')
```

But I'm not real happy with the results because I feel that the range of rows will never be single digits and the random calculation that I do just doesn't seem that great at creating a real random number from row 1 to row-max-number. I'm not exactly sure how many rows are in the orders table in the first place which could be another issue.

Is there a better method to finding random rows in a table?

Comment: Why not simple do SELECT TOP ... ORDER BY NEWID() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do it this way:

```
select TOP 30 *
from orders o inner join
     store s
     on o.Retailer_ID = s.ID
where s.Name='XXXX'
order by newid();
```

This is returning random rows by randomly sorting the data and then choosing the top 30 rows.  In SQL Server, ordering by `newid()` is a way to randomly sort the data.

Comment: Thank you very much, looks like a nice query. So every time I run this query, I will get different orders for a given store? I tried to run this on my server, and I didn't get any rows?

Comment: @JeromeLandis . . . I just noticed that the `in` clause is redundant, but that shouldn't cause any filtering of the rows.  Does the query return anything without the `order by`?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It does return rows now. The issue might be that I do not have many rows in my test system, so I will try to add another 50 rows or so and see if I can generate random rows with the query every time. One thing that I really don't understand is how it is generating random rows. If you comment about that, that would be excellent. I think the order by newid() has something to do with it, but I don't understand why it is there... thank you sir!

Comment: Now it makes sense. Order by a random number, great idea. Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

Things are much simpler.

```
   select TOP 30 *
    from orders o 
         join store s on o.Retailer_ID=s.ID
    where s.Name='XXXX'
    order by newid()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, looks like a nice query. So every time I run this query, I will get different orders for a given store? I tried to run this on my server, and I didn't get any rows?